# Show/Hide Javascript one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is probably very simple but I'm at a loss.

I have two anchors that toggle the display of their own div containers. Right now, you can have both div containers showing by clicking each button once. I would like only one div showing at a time.

So if you select button 1 to show div 1, then you select button 2, it will show div 2 but also hide div 1.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  function ReverseDisplay(d) 
  {
    if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") 
      { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
    else 
      { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
  }
</script>

<a id="menus" href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('menuList')">Button 1</a>
<a id="reso" href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('resoList')">Button 2</a>

<p>Some content</p>

<div id="menuList" style="display:none;">Some content</div>
<div id="resoList" style="display:none;">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery or just vanilla JS?

Comment: In the function, store an array of Div Ids. Hide all of them except the one passed in as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Give div's common class

```
<div id="menuList" class="content" style="display:none;">Some content 1</div>
<div id="resoList" class="content" style="display:none;">Some content 2</div>
```

And then hide all before showing specific:

```
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.content')).forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });

    var element = document.getElementById(d);
    element.style.display = element.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Check the demo below.

```js
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.content')).forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });
    
    var element = document.getElementById(d);
    element.style.display = element.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<a id="menus" href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('menuList')">Button 1</a>
<a id="reso" href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('resoList')">Button 2</a>

<p>Some content</p>

<div id="menuList" class="content" style="display:none;">Some content 1</div>
<div id="resoList" class="content" style="display:none;">Some content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging and I found a solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
(function() { 
    var opened_element = null;

    window.ReverseDisplay = function(d) {
       var e = document.getElementById(d);
       if (opened_element && opened_element !== e) {
           opened_element.style.display = 'none';
       }
       if(e.style.display == 'block') {
          e.style.display = 'none';
       }
       else {
          e.style.display = 'block';
       }
       opened_element = e;
    };
}());</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

```js
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  var el = document.getElementById(d),
    els = document.getElementsByClassName('list'),
    c;
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    c = els[i];
    if (el == c) {
      if (el.style.display == "block") {
        el.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        el.style.display = "block";
      }
    } else {
      c.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="menus" href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('menuList')">Button 1</a>
<a id="reso" href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('resoList')">Button 2</a>
<p>Some content</p>
<div id="menuList" class="list">Some content 1</div>
<div id="resoList" class="list">Some content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is jQuery for those that could use this:

```
function hideTarget(elem){
    $(elem).hide();
}

function showTarget(elem, target, hideThis){
    $(elem).click(function(){
        $(target).show();
        hideTarget(hideThis);
    });
}


showTarget('#reso','#resoList','#menuList');
showTarget('#menus','#menuList','#resoList');
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/23qmt0j2/)